# The blog search box shows an horizontal scrollbar

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, blog

The [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) search box shows a very ***old school*** horizontal scrollbar.

Tested on *Firefox 3.6.16* | *OSX 10.5.8*

[image]

Comment: Confirmed on Firefox 4 beta on OS X 10.6 too. And it also has some weird zoom behavior: zooming in or out makes the whole side column move below the main content. (No issues on Safari and Chrome.)

Comment: @Arj yep, No issue on Safari/Chrome and FF on Windows XP :)

Comment: Weird: removing `text-align` from `#sidebar{ font-size: 1.4em; text-align: right; }` fixes this... Smells like a Firefox bug then. (And my zoom settings were "Zoom text only", which may be unrelated then.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is fixed now. If it isn't let me know.

Comment: sorry Jeff, it's still there. Note: I've upgraded to FF 5.0.1

Comment: how about now? I removed the css entry Arjan mentioned above

Comment: this is now fixed